# Reproduce a C function pointer array in Python

Tags: python, c

I have a Python program asking the user for input like a shell, and if I detect some specific keywords I want to go inside some specific functions.

The thing is that I would like to avoid doing a lot of `if` and `else if`. Usually in C to avoid this situation I use a function pointer array that I travel with a `while` and use `strcmp` to check the input.

I would like to know how to do that in Python if it is even possible.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/3001761? For those of us not *au fait* with C, it might be helpful to provide more information about what you're talking about.

Comment: Maybe you want a dictionary mapping string keys to functions? I don't understand why you would need to use a while loop in C.

Comment: @Shashank you could use a while loop if the array of function pointers was NULL terminated.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary is what I need apparently, thank you!

(and yes I use a NULL terminated array for my loop in C)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python you use a [***dictionary***](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Example:

```
keyword2func = {
    "word1": function_word1,
    "word2": function_word2,
}

word = input("")
keyword2func[word]()
```